# Implementing Metropolis-Hasting for multiple variables

Tags: python, multivariate-analysis, markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings

Working through a lecture exercise on MCMC methods. I have a dataset containing the outcome of N chess games $-$ in the format *Winner, Loser* $-$ between M players.

When 2 players $p_1$ and $p_2$ play against one another in game $g$, the outcome is modeled as $y_g = sign(W_{p_1} - W_{p_2} + v_g)$, where:

- $W_{p_i}$ represents the skill of player $p_i$. As a prior, all players have their skills $W_{p_i}$ ~ $N(0,1)$ (so all players are i.i.d),
- $W_{p_1} - W_{p_2}$ is the skill difference between $p_1$ and $p_2$,
- $v_g$ ~ $Laplace(0, \frac{1}{2})$ models the performance variance of both players jointly.

I would like to find values of $W$ that maximize the likelihood of all N games across all M players. To do so, I would like to practice implementing Metropolis-Hastings (MH) on that dataset, in Python. I understand the MH algorithm as the following (from [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/from-scratch-bayesian-inference-markov-chain-monte-carlo-and-metropolis-hastings-in-python-ef21a29e25a)):

Given:

- $f$, the PDF of the distribution to sample from,
- $w^{0}$, initial values for $W$,
- $w = w^{0}$,
- The transition model, which here is given as a Gaussian distribution $w^{t+1}_{p_i}$ ~ $N(w^{t}_{p_i},\sigma_p)$, with $\sigma_p$ a hyper-parameter,

For n steps:

- $p = f(y |W=w)P(w)$,
- $w'$ ~ $N(w^{t}_{p_i},\sigma_p)$
- $p' = f(y |W=w')P(w')$,
- $ratio = \frac{p'}{p}$
- Draw $r$ from $U(0,1)$, if $ratio > r$, set $w^{t+1}_{p_i} = w'$

**Questions**

1. Is my understanding of MH correct?
2. I have seen Python examples which implement MH for a single variable. IIUC, here, we have M variables - one skill per player. How can I implement MH for a multi-variate case? Or am I completely off?

Sorry about the long post. I'll update as needed if it isn't clear. Thanks!

**Edit 1** Just clarifying that I'm interested in code examples using MH on vectors of parameters, not a single scalar.

Comment: $W$ is a vector of dimension $M$ and $y$ of dimension $N$. This is standard Metropolis Hastings.

Comment: MH is used to draw samples from some distribution you cannot characterize ($f$ in your notation), but you can evaluate some function proportional to said distribution. This is useful when one wants to draw samples from a posterior distribution, for example.  However, there is really no scope for the MH in the maximum likelihood estimation you described. In other words, what is $f$ in your example?

Comment: @Banach you are correct, $f$ in this case is the posterior ($P(W | y)$), which is intractable. The above (in my understanding) uses Bayes's theorem to use the likelihood $P(y|W)$ instead, which is tractable.

Comment: @Xi'an Yes, I agree with you. My problem is how can I implement MH for vectors instead of scalars? The examples I've seen so far all deal with scalars.

Comment: Here is an example: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/525373/7224 And another one https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/441746/7224 The algorithm does not change in essence, all you need is a multivariate proposal to move the vector rather than the scalar.